# How to edit the Amasty Magento One Page Checkout page in front end to add a label in payment method section?

Tags: magento, checkout, amasty

I am trying to add a label in my Magento One Page Checkout.  I am using Amasty One Page Checkout extension.  I want to add a text under Payment Method Credit Card Number.  Not able to find the file. Any help would be appreciated.

I tried find the files, but not able to find the right file and path.

Comment: Maybe this general answer to label / subtitle of payment information (not specific to your extension!) will help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266220/magento-2-checkout-payment-method-add-subtitle/266301#266301

Answer (score 0):

You can use template hints in "System-->Configuration-->Developer". You first need to change scope to storeview. And you can better use allowed IP's.